# My dynamic queue in C is displaying infinite weird results

Tags: c, pointers, gcc, linked-list

I'm studyind dinamic lists in C and this is a queue that I made using structs and pointers, it is queueing the nodes normally but when I call the Dequeue and Show methods in that order, it enter in a loop and displays weird random numbers.

```
struct Node {
    int data;
    struct Node *next;
};

typedef struct Node node;
int size = 0;

node* front = NULL;
node* rear = NULL;
```

//adds a new node at the end of the list
    void Enqueue(int n){

```
    node *new_node = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));

    new_node->data = n;
    new_node->next = NULL;

    if (front == NULL && rear == NULL){
        front = new_node;
        rear = new_node;
        return;
    }

    rear->next = new_node;
    rear = new_node;
}
```

//when calling this method before show(), the loop issue occurs
    void Dequeue(){

`node *tmp = front;


    if (front == rear){
        front = rear = NULL;
    }

    else {
        front = front->next;
    }
    free(front);
}

//if just calling Enqueue() and Show() methods, it runs normally
void Show(){

    node *tmp = front;

    while(tmp != NULL){

        printf("%d \n", tmp->data);
        tmp = tmp->next;
    }
}


int main(void){

    Enqueue(1);
    Enqueue(2);
    Enqueue(3);


    Dequeue();
    Show();

    system("pause");
    return 0; 
}`

Comment: Sidenote: C does not support _methods_. You have _functions_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `free(front);`

I think you mean:

```
free(tmp);
```

Just before your call to `free()`, you reassign `front` to point to the new head of the queue, so freeing that node isn't what you want to do. `tmp` is a copy of the pointer to the original head node, and it's safe to free that one after you've reassigned `front`.

Answer (score 1):

Check your `Dequeue(...)` function.  You're freeing the node on the front after re-assigning it.  Try this instead

```
void Dequeue(){


node *tmp = front;


if (front == rear){
    front = rear = NULL;
}

else {
    front = front->next;
}
free(tmp);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
free(front);  // SHOULD BE `free(tmp)`
```

---

*The correct code*

```
void Dequeue(){
    node *tmp = front;

    if (front == rear)
        front = rear = NULL;
        else
            front = front->next;
   free(tmp);
}
```

Comment: `temp` it's just a auxiliary, so you sould not use the `free`, in `Enqueue` he has allocated `*new_node`, it´s different.

Comment: @FábioMorais You have to free it, otherwise you would have a memory leak. Your first example also does not make sense, since you are not freeing the memory which was allocated in `Deqeue()`.

Comment: That's weird, the OP has allocated `new_node ` in the `Deqeue()`, and the `new_node ` is a `local` variable, so you can't freeing the memory. Here, `tmp` its just pointing to `front`, just that. But I may be wrong, because you're not the only one how say that I have to freeing the memory.

Comment: I get it now, so sorry, I'm a little stubborn

Comment: @user3121023 yeah yeah, you right, I haven't seen that, damn